# two ACM devices does not function together

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-indigo, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use hokuyo lidar and arduino for my application. Hokuyo is connected to laptop directly and it is connected as ACM port.
Arduino board connected to the laptop is ACM1. Now, whenever I upload a new code in arduino using rosserial, while the lidar is also connected to the laptop, it shows following error.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

If I remove either of the device from the laptop, then the other one works. Please do help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287539/two-acm-devices-does-not-function-together/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try to use some udev rules as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters

But the easiest and quickest way is probably to use the symlinks in `/dev/serial/by-id/`, for example `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-SparkFun_SparkFun_Pro_Micro-if00`.

---

Originally posted by [lalten](https://answers.ros.org/users/25550/lalten/) with karma: 102 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0